# dropwizard logs are not getting rolledover

Tags: logback, dropwizard

Below is my logging configuration in config.yml file.I am running my service for 2 days but my logs didn't roll over.

Please help if below is correct or how can debug this.

logging:

# Permit DEBUG, INFO, WARN and ERROR messages to be logged by appenders.
  level: OFF
  loggers:

```
"mylogger": INFO
```

appenders:
    - type: console
      threshold: DEBUG
      target: stderr

```
# Log info, warnings and errors to our apps' main log.
- type: file
  threshold: DEBUG
  currentLogFilename: /var/log/discovery/discovery-service.log
  archivedLogFilenamePattern: /var/log/discovery/discovery-service-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz
  archivedFileCount: 7
  archive: true
  logFormat: "%msg\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your archivedLogFilenamePattern is incorrect. Remove "-%i" and it should work.